# Multiplicity of roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Suppose $P$ is a polynomial of degree $2n$ with complex coefficients such that $P(z)=z^{2n}\overline{P(1/\bar{z})}$.

I want to show that the roots of $P$ on the unit circle are of even multiplicity.

1. What method do you suggest for proving this?
2. Is it possible to use the fact that if $a$ is a root of $P$ with $|a|>1$, then so is $1/\bar{a}$ with the same multiplicity in the proof of 1?

Comment: In your note $2$, why do you need the inequality in $|a|>1$?  If $|a|=1$, then $a=1/\overline{a}$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr I know that the statement that I mentioned in fact 2 holds when $a\ne 1/\bar{a}$ that is when $a$ is not on the unit circle. So I just assume that $|a|>1$. I wonder if with some method (like taking limits?) this fact can be used to prove something about the roots on the unit circle.

Comment: FWIW one conclusion which follows from point `2` is that the number of roots on the unit circle must be even (counting multiplicities). So in the case of a single root on the unit circle, that must be of even multiplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counterexample for $n=1$: $$P(z)=z^2+1 = z^2\left(1 + \frac{1}{z^2}\right)= z^2\overline{\left(\frac{1}{\bar z^2}+1\right)} = z^2 \overline{P\left(\frac{1}{\bar z}\right)}$$

But $P(z)$ has the simple roots $\pm i$ on the unit circle.

All that can be derived from the given condition is that $a_k = \overline{a_{2n-k}}$ where $P(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n} a_k z^k$, or otherwise said $P(z)$ is [conjugate reciprocal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial#Conjugate_reciprocal_polynomials).